# Does the equality $\int _{[0,1]^n+a}f(x)d\lambda (x)=\int_{[0,1]^n}f(x)d\lambda (x)$ holds for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ if $f$ is $1$-periodic?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, periodic-functions

Let $\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda :\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the Lebesgue measure.

**Definition:** We say that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is $1$**-periodic** if $f(x+k)=f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$.

**My question is:** Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is a non-negative measurable function. Does the equality $\int _{[0,1]^n+a}f(x)d\lambda (x)=\int_{[0,1]^n}f(x)d\lambda (x)$ holds for all $a\color{red}{\in\mathbb{R}^n}$ if $f$ is $1$-periodic?

---

Unfortunately I didn't make any progress.

The only thing is worth mentioning is that we can assume without loss of generality that $a\in [0,1)^n$ because there's $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $a-k\in [0,1)^n$ and we have

$\int _{[0,1]^n+a}f(x)d\lambda (x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]^n+a}(x)f(x)d\lambda (x)=$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]^n+a}(x+k)f(x+k)d\lambda (x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]^n+a-k}(x)f(x)d\lambda (x)=$

$\int_{[0,1]^n+a-k}f(x)d\lambda (x)$

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: It holds because $\int_{[0,1]^n}f(x-a)dx=\int_{[0,1]^n}f(x)\,\mathrm d x$ for all $a$.

Comment: @Surb But why this equality holds? I tried using the Change of Variable Theorem but I couldn't get this equality.

Comment: You should induct on the number $N$ of coordinates in $a$ that do not lie in $\mathbb{Z}$.  If $N=0$, then it's immediate by Surb's comment (because $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$).  If $N>0$, you can cut the cube into two pieces and shift one by an element of the Euclidean basis $e_i$ so that the new integral has one more coordinate that is an integer.

Comment: You can try to draw a picture for $n=2$. $[0,1]^2+a$ is the unit square translated by $a$, and it is divided by the grids into $4$ pieces in general, and translating them appropriately gives $[0,1]^2$ back.

Comment: For an interval, decompose it into $[0,a]$ and $[a,1]$ and then use periodicity to show the sum of the two integrals over those two subintervals are the same as the integrals over $[a,1]$ and $[1,1+a]$ because the integral over $[0,a]$ and $[1,1+a]$ are equal by periodicity. Then for dimensions higher than 1, use induction as [Brian Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/694754/brian-moehring) said. I vote for that answer.